# Cython: Cannot convert Python object to struct

Tags: python, cython

Warning: I am pretty newbie with Cython. :D
I have the following pieces of code:

my_structs.h:

```
typedef struct Dataset{
    int lines;
    char **tid;
}Dataset;
```

myiolib.pyx:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.string cimport strcpy
from cpython.string cimport PyString_AsString

cdef extern from "my_structs.h":
    cdef struct Dataset:
        int lines
        char **tid


cdef Dataset readDataset(TID_name):
    cdef:
        int i, line_count=0
        Dataset instance

    with open(TID_name, 'rU') as file_iter:
        for line in file_iter:
            line_count=line_count+1

    instance.tid = <char **>malloc(line_count * sizeof(char *))

    i = 0
    with open(TID_name, 'rU') as file_iter:
        for line in file_iter:
            instance.tid[i] = <char *>malloc((len(line)+1) * sizeof(char ))
            strcpy(instance.tid[i], PyString_AsString(line.strip()))
            i += 1

    instance.lines = line_count
    return instance
```

mytest.pyx:

```
import myiolib

cdef extern from "my_structs.h":
    cdef struct Dataset:
        int lines
        char **tid


def test():
    cdef Dataset D
    D = myiolib.readDataset("test.dat")

    # Do something...
    # Free memory (?!)
```

test.py:

```
import mytest

mytest.test()
```

When I type: cython -a mytest.pyx it says: "Cannot convert Python object to 'Dataset' ", 
pointing at D = myiolib.readDataset("test.dat").
Why? I don't understand... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your minimal example is pretty bad. You don't include a `setup.py` or any other way of running the code.

As such, here's a proper minimal example:

`test_python.py`

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs': "."})

import my_test

my_test.test()
```

`my_test.pyx`

```
import my_library

cdef extern from "my_type.h":
    cdef struct MyType:
        int x

def test():
    cdef MyType my_instance
    my_object = my_library.my_function()
```

`my_library.pyx`

```
cdef extern from "my_type.h":
    cdef struct MyType:
        int x

cdef MyType my_function():
    return MyType()
```

`my_type.h`

```
typedef struct MyType {
    int my_attribute;
} MyType;
```

This errors with:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'my_function'
```

This is because `cdef` is being used, so `import` will not allow access to the function. You've used `cdef` too, so I'm surprised this isn't happening with you. Maybe compiling with `setup.py` doesn't require this; it wouldn't surprise me. Even then, though, you're using `import` where you should be using `cimport`.

Add a `my_library.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "my_type.h":
    cdef struct MyType:
        int x

cdef MyType my_function()
```

optionally remove `cdef extern` from the `pyx` file and change

```
import my_library
```

to

```
cimport my_library
```

and it works.

If these tips don't fix it for you, please give me an example I can run.

Comment: That's it! Many thanks.
Sorry for not giving the setup.py. I totally forgot it! :/